# How to show and Hide the checkboxes in Primeng table based on selection

Tags: angular, primeng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYo1C.png)>

> <p-tableCheckbox [value]="configDetailsData">

> Disable the check boxes based on Condition.

Comment: What is the selection? What is the criteria for hiding/showing? Where is rest of the code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In general, to hide any html based on a condition you can use `[style.visibility]` or `[style.display]` depending on if you want the element to continue taking up space.

**Takes space when hidden**

```html
<p-tableCheckbox
  [style.visibility]="*condition* ? 'hidden' : 'visible'"
  [value]="configDetailsData"
></p-tableCheckbox>
```

**Does not take space when hidden**

```html
<p-tableCheckbox
  [style.display]="*condition* ? 'none' : 'initial'"
  [value]="configDetailsData"
></p-tableCheckbox>
```